# Mixing two arrays together

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void add_charArray(char a[100], int i, char b[100], int j, char c[100], int k)
{
    using namespace std;
    char temp;
    char temp_2;

    for (int start = 0; start < i; start + 2)
    {
        int start_2 = 1;
        temp = a[start] ;
        temp_2 = b[start];
        c[start] = temp;
        c[start_2] = temp_2;
        start_2 + 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j , k;
    char first_array[100];
    char second_array[100];
    char write_array[100]; 
    cout <<"tell me two strings: "<<endl;
    cin >> first_array;
    cin >> second_array;
    i = strlen(first_array); 
    j = strlen(second_array);
    k = i + j;
    add_charArray(first_array, i, second_array, j, write_array, k);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a function that takes two arrays and mixes them together so that once a user types:

`ugfbk//for the first`

`abjq//for the second`

The function write into a third array like this
`uagbfjbqk`

This is practice for an intro to c++ course so any pointers would be great

Comment: the objective is for the user to input two arrays and for those array to mixed into another third  array with the letters being mixed in this fashion:     abcdef// this is input 1  tuvwxyz // this is input 2

Comment: Did you have a specific question?  What's not working?

Comment: no the mixing is not random they are put in the new array in a particular order. the first letter should be the from the first array and the second letter should be the first letter fro the second array and they should alternate in that fashion until all the letters are put into the array

Comment: the code is not working past the input of the first two arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void add_charArray(char a[100], int i, char b[100], int j, char c[100], int k)
{
int start,start_2,start_f;

for(start = 0,start_2=0,start_f=0; start < i; start++,start_2++)
{
        c[start_f++]=a[start];
        c[start_f++]=b[start_2];
}

while(start_2 < j)
c[start_f++]=b[start_2++];

c[start_f]='\0';

cout<<c;

}
```

I am yet to see your implementation.I don't think you really need `temp` variables

Comment: I a really having a hard time understanding why my questions get down votes when the purpose of my question has been made clear and I have my code on display. I don't know whats wrong with this "community", but if you guys don't want to help then just dont. There is need to be jerks about it....sheesh

Comment: Thanks for the actual help @VusP. At least you tried to help.

Comment: @WillH. Welcome. I am glad it helped you. Coming to the downvote part, I guess that's because you hadn't added your problem `the code is not working past the input of the first two arrays` to the question initially. That single line can help people narrow down to the error and help you better :) Imagine going to a doctor and saying I am not well, and the doctor has to do all the tests to find out whats wrong. If you go and tell him I am not well, my stomach aches. That reduces the no of tests the doctor has to conduct. :)